# nodejs request function inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, https, request

I have this arrays with **8 items** each

```
var array_pullrequest_id=["335","328","326","323","322","314","295","291"];
var array_uniqueName=["A@A.com","B@B.com","C@C.com","D@D.com","E@E.com","F@F.com","G@G.com","H@H.com"];
```

I'm trying to do a post request with each index of the arrays:

```
 function test2(){
   
    var array_pullrequest_id=["335","328","326","323","322","314","295","291"];
    var array_uniqueName=["A@A.com","B@B.com","C@C.com","D@D.com","E@E.com","F@F.com","G@G.com","H@H.com"];
    var count = 8;
     for (var i=0; i<count; i++){
     
    var pullRequests_id = array_pullrequest_id[i];    
    var createdBy = array_uniqueName[i];
  
  console.log("first index: " + i);
  console.log("first console log pullRequest ID: " + pullRequests_id);
  console.log("first console log Created by: " + createdBy);

  var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://HIDEN_URL/pullRequests/'+ pullRequests_id+'/workitems',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Basic HIDEN_AUTH',
    'Cookie': 'HIDEN_COOKIE'
  }
}
request(options, function (error, response) { 
    console.log("second index: " + i);
    console.log("second console log pullRequest ID: " + pullRequests_id);
    console.log("second console log Created by: " + createdBy);

});
}
 }
```

NoW this is the console output:

```
first index: 0
first console log pullRequest: 335
first console log Created by: A@A.com
first index: 1
first console log pullRequest: 328
first console log Created by: B@B.com
first index: 2
first console log pullRequest: 326
first console log Created by: C@C.com
first index: 3
first console log pullRequest ID: 323
first console log Created by: D@D.com
first index: 4
first console log pullRequest ID: 322
first console log Created by: E@E.com
first index: 5
first console log pullRequest ID: 314
first console log Created by: F@F.com
first index: 6
first console log pullRequest ID: 295
first console log Created by: G@G.com
first index: 7
first console log pullRequest ID: 291
first console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
second index: 8
second console log pullRequest ID: 291
second console log Created by: H@H.com
```

Now as you can see the **first console log** items are print correctly following the count variable index, but inside the for loop request function **(second console log)** its only printing the last array item, even if its inside the loop, it just take the last, it just doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: request is an async function I believe, so the first console log and the second console log are not executed in order. the loop finish first, and then the request function will get the last variables value set at the end of the loop, that's why the second console log are printing 291 and H2H.com

Comment: @grandia What other way of doing http request in nodejs that are not async do you recommend me?

Comment: I would recommend using other framework as request seems to be deprecated.

I have used axios and fetch, and I think both are great. And for making it synchronous, you can use async/await. Are you familiar with async/await?

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations i'm not familiarized with async/await, but i'll try to change to those frameworks :)!

Comment: sure, let me post a code for it

Comment: Thankyou grandia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have installed axios, you can use async/await like below

notice the `async` keyword in front of the `function test2()`

now `test2` is an async function

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function test2(){
   
    var array_pullrequest_id=["335","328","326","323","322","314","295","291"];
    var array_uniqueName=["A@A.com","B@B.com","C@C.com","D@D.com","E@E.com","F@F.com","G@G.com","H@H.com"];
    var count = 8;
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++){

        var pullRequests_id = array_pullrequest_id[i];    
        var createdBy = array_uniqueName[i];

        console.log("first index: " + i);
        console.log("first console log pullRequest ID: " + pullRequests_id);
        console.log("first console log Created by: " + createdBy);

        var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': 'https://HIDEN_URL/pullRequests/'+ pullRequests_id+'/workitems',
        'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Basic HIDEN_AUTH',
        'Cookie': 'HIDEN_COOKIE'
            }
        }
        await axios(options)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("second index: " + i);
            console.log("second console log pullRequest ID: " + pullRequests_id);
            console.log("second console log Created by: " + createdBy);
        })
        
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the **second console log** prints only the last item in the array because it's inside `request` which is an `asynchronous` function, which means while `request` function is running in the background to return a promise the rest of your code outside the request function is running as normal and so the loop keeps iterating until the last item in the array

Answer (score 0):

Making service request is blocking in nature so we should use either callbacks or promises to get output as you expect. try to use asyncForEach with this you can able to achieve above output.

```
async function test2() {

    var array_pullrequest_id = ["335", "328", "326", "323", "322", "314", "295", "291"];
    var array_uniqueName = ["A@A.com", "B@B.com", "C@C.com", "D@D.com", "E@E.com", "F@F.com", "G@G.com", "H@H.com"];
    var count = 8;

    await asyncForEach(array_pullrequest_id, async(pullrequest, index) => {
        var pullRequests_id = array_pullrequest_id[index];
        var createdBy = array_uniqueName[index];

        console.log("first index: " + index);
        console.log("first console log pullRequest ID: " + pullRequests_id);
        console.log("first console log Created by: " + createdBy);

        var options = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'url': 'https://HIDEN_URL/pullRequests/' + pullRequests_id + '/workitems',
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': 'Basic HIDEN_AUTH',
                'Cookie': 'HIDEN_COOKIE'
            }
        }
        request(options, function(error, response) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log("second index: " + index);
            console.log("second console log pullRequest ID: " + pullRequests_id);
            console.log("second console log Created by: " + createdBy);

        });
    });
}

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        await callback(array[index], index, array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async for loop "if your node version supports it" , as said above the problem with your code is that the request is asynchronous by nature.